# Logstash Reading all ELB logs from s3 not just current

Tags: amazon-s3, logging, logstash, elk, log-analysis

Logstash is reading all ELB logs files stored on the s3 bucket but I want it read-only current logs not all.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [ask] a question.  You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Logstash faces a performance issue with a large set of files.
So the best practice to move the previous file into the backup s3 bucket and set in logstash to delete the file after reading and copy to the backup bucket so it only reads new files.